# event.data is undefined for SSE client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-sent-events

I have a class component that gets alerts from server in real time using JavsScript EventSource API. But it doesn't seem to be working. onmessage method of SSE object doesn't get executed and it closes connection due to onerror method. I guess data attribute is not available in event so how do i get the data returned by API?

```
    componentDidMount() {
        page_number = 1
        const sse = new EventSource(obj.django_api_server+'/monitoring/alertsws/?resolved=False&page='+page_number);
        // sse.onopen = function(event) {
        //   console.log(event.data);
        //   console.log("alerts received from server");
        // };
        sse.onmessage = function(event) {
          // this.forceUpdate()
          console.log(event.data);
          console.log("New alert received from server");
        };
        sse.onerror = function(event) {
          console.log(event.error);
          console.log("closing connection");
          sse.close()
        };
      }
    }
```

Console printing the event gives(don't contain any attribute like message). It is not expanded completely as it seems very long

```
    Event {isTrusted: true, type: "open", target: EventSource, currentTarget: EventSource, eventPhase: 2, …}
    bubbles: false
    cancelBubble: false
    cancelable: false
    composed: false
    currentTarget: EventSource {url: "https://www.monitoring-alert-dev.allthingswordpress.io/monitoring/alertsws/?resolved=False&page=1", withCredentials: false, readyState: 2, onopen: ƒ, onmessage: ƒ, …}
    defaultPrevented: false
    eventPhase: 0
    isTrusted: true
    path: []
    returnValue: true
    srcElement: EventSource {url: "https://www.monitoring-alert-dev.allthingswordpress.io/monitoring/alertsws/?resolved=False&page=1", withCredentials: false, readyState: 2, onopen: ƒ, onmessage: ƒ, …}
    target: EventSource {url: "https://www.monitoring-alert-dev.allthingswordpress.io/monitoring/alertsws/?resolved=False&page=1", withCredentials: false, readyState: 2, onopen: ƒ, onmessage: ƒ, …}
    timeStamp: 27382.45499995537
    type: "open"
```

Comment: What are the outputs of the `console.logs`?

Comment: undefined and closing connection. So onerror method is being executed

Comment: Console log the ‘event’ only. Not ‘event.error’

Comment: it logs the eventSource object with many attribute but i can't find data.

Comment: Can you copy and paste that object here. Then only we can pin point the error. You are going to the error callback because the sse object it self returns an error. That’s probably why the data property is undefined

Comment: it's clickable in console and it keeps on expanding. How do i copy all of it?

Comment: No need to copy all of it. It should have a property named "message"

Comment: it doesn't contain message attribute. i have question with event printed. Have a look. thanks

Comment: It seems like you are getting the error thrown while connecting to the server. And also you are not sending any credentials to the api. Are you sure that’s intended? If you copy and paste the api url in the browser does it show your the server sent event?

Comment: yes, resources on server aren't protected. Am I connecting to server in wrong way?

Comment: If the resources aren’t protected then it should be ok. Maybe the issue is in the php code where echo the event. Can we see that code as well? Also if the url is not protected it’s best that you remove the full request url from your question above

Comment: i'm getting correct response in postman with correct header. Content-type set to text/event-stream.